# Apache problem with Mod Rewrite all POST have been redirected to GET with R=501 before the rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, certbot

I've this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END}  =1
RewriteRule ^                    -                    [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^/?([\w]+)/([0-9\.]+)/assets/(.*)" "/assets/$1/$3" [L,E=END:1]
RewriteRule ^verifycode/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ vercode.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule "^/?([\w]+)/([0-9\.]+)/(.*)$"       "/clients/jsonrest.php/$1/$2/$3"  [R=307]
```

I'm calling this URL via POST:
https://s1.****.com//I2amZMjAK6q8nmkuBY3TEK1jkqgZyQ4S/1.3/getclientid

In the rewrite log (error.log) using

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
```

directive, the rule is matched correctly but in request.log (access.log) I've this:

```
*.*.119.49 - - [09/Sep/2021:07:03:53 +0000] "POST /I2amZMjAK6q8nmkuBY3TEK1jkqgZyQ4S/1.3/getclientid HTTP/1.1" 301 283 "-" "BDSSport/1.06.07 (com.bizdev-strategy.container; build:2397; iOS 12.5.4) Alamofire/5.1.0"
*.*.119.49 - - [09/Sep/2021:07:03:54 +0000] "GET /I2amZMjAK6q8nmkuBY3TEK1jkqgZyQ4S/1.3/getclientid HTTP/1.1" 307 306 "-" "BDSSport/1.06.07 (com.bizdev-strategy.container; build:2397; iOS 12.5.4) Alamofire/5.1.0"
*.*.119.49 - - [09/Sep/2021:07:03:54 +0000] "GET /clients/jsonrest.php/I2amZMjAK6q8nmkuBY3TEK1jkqgZyQ4S/1.3/getclientid HTTP/1.1" 200 161 "-" "BDSSport/1.06.07 (com.bizdev-strategy.container; build:2397; iOS 12.5.4) Alamofire/5.1.0"
```

Any POST call is redirected immediately to a GET first with 301, then rewrote using my rule 307. Of course, I lost my POST data and my API doesn't work properly. The client, iOS phones, crash.

From where this POST to GET arrives ? It is more than a day looking for logs and API code and the client's code.

I think the issue is on the Apache side I'm using:
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 ()
Server built:   Apr  2 2020 05:50:15

On another Apache server everything was working fine, same .htaccess, same code.

The problem was originated only on iPhone App since the app was calling http:// instead https:// and the  redirection in Apache was not correctly configured (see comment below).

As usual a human mistake, Alamo 5, iOS, Apache and PHP all working fine. Hope this can save time to someone else. I spent 2 days to debug APACHE, Api Code and Apps.

Comment: Why are you trying to redirect this externally to begin with, why is this not just an internal rewrite? Making the client send the same amount of POST data a second time, that just seems wasteful.

Comment: Yes it is an internal rewrite but I don't know how to do it :-( Any help is appreciate

Comment: The `R` flag is what's causing the external redirect to begin with.

Comment: I modified my .htaccess with `RewriteRule     ^/?([\w]+)/([0-9\.]+)/(.+)$             /clients/jsonrest.php/$1/$2/$3`  The problem is still with iPhone/iPad devices, Android, Postman and manual CURL works. I catch the POST data with `file_get_contents("php://input")` but  from iPhone  this is empty probably due to the redirection that still happens even restart, clear and reinstall the App. I don't  how to clear this behaviour.

Comment: FIXED, in reality the problem was only on iPhone (Alamofire 5) because that App was still calling http://  instead https:// even if insecure connection are banned. The  previous server operates the redirection correctly  since I spent a lot of time on it and I made the correct redirection syntax `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=307]` instead the general but not good for POST redirection `RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]` suggested by certbot.

Comment: If you fixed it then answer your own question. Don't add `(fixed)` to the title. This is not a forum.